# Assign a property to a variable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How can I assign a property (in this case `status.val`) to a variable in `ng-repeat` so that I can apply translation to it like the one used above `translation.status`?

Can I do something like `ng-repeat="status in statusList; a=status.val"` ?

```
<div>
  <label for="status">{{translation.status}}</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="status" ng-model="extraItemForm.status" ng-required="true">
    <option ng-repeat="status in statusList" value="{{status.id}}">
      {{status.val}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example with the issues and expected result if possible screenshots!

Comment: Can you give an example for values in `statusList` and how you like it rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init`

html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors" ng-init="test = mentor">{{test}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope ) {
    $scope.mentors = [ 'Jonathan', 'Nathan', 'Chris', 'Brian', 'Timothy' ];
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p592quf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-options` inside `select` and add translate:

```
<select ng-model="me.gender" ng-options="gender.name | translate for gender in genders"></select>
```

[See the example on this link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ViSF2DWK1amSW8BwwPKn?p=preview&preview)